# Sysdate in where clause not working in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have below select query where i am trying to get the data only for today date but its not returning anything:

```
select * from V_TER
where SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT = SYSDATE;
```

The `SYSTEM_INSERTED_DATE` is of `Date` datatype and the value is stored in this fields as for example `2021-01-15 15:17:13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in Oracle is that dates can have time components both in the data and `sysdate` itself.

I would recommend checking for any time on the current date:

```
where system_inserted_at >= trunc(sysdate) and
      system_inserted_at < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day
```

This is generally optimizer-friendly.  If you don't care about that, then:

```
where trunc(system_inserted_at) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: thanks where trunc(system_inserted_at) = trunc(sysdate)  works for me

Comment: @Symonds It will "work" but i you have an index on the `system_inserted_at` column then Oracle cannot use it if you truncate the column (you would need a function-based index instead) but it could use it if you compare on a range of dates (without truncating the column).